# Problem with .splitting a line in a fashion when there is no delimiter

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have a text file ;

> ... Above in Table 5 , we understood the relationship between pressure
>   and volume. It said ... and now we know ... . Table 9: represents the
>   graph of x and y. Table 6 was all about force and it implications on
>   objects....

Now I have written a code to extract the lines that have the word table in it;

```
with open file( <pathname + filename.txt>, 'r+') as f:
   k = f.readlines()
   for line in k:
     if ' Table ' in line:
         print(line)
```

Now I desire to print the output in a particular format;

> (txt file name),(Table id),(Table content)

I do this by using the **.split method of python;**

```
x = 'Paper ID:' + filename.split('.')[0] + '|' + 'Table ID:' + line.split(':')[0] + '|' + 'Table Content:' + line.split(':')[1] + '|'
```

Now,as you can see, I can separate the table id and table content where there is a delimiter ( :) after some .
**How do I do the same where there is no delimiter, i.e. for these lines;**

> Above in Table 5 , we understood the relationship between pressure
>   and volume. It said ... and now we know ..
>   Or
>   In table 7 we saw....

**?**

Could anyone please help?

Comment: I think you should have a look at regular expressions (short regex). The following could work: `Table\W[0-9](.*)Table\W[0-9]` where group 1 is your table content .  Resources: https://regex101.com/ or https://regexr.com/ for testing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression python_specific: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the pattern `Table <number>` then split at that location.
You could use `re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)` or `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`

```
re.split('Table [0-9]', line)[-1]
```

will give you what follows (the content).

```
re.findall('Table [0-9]', line)
```

will give you the table with its ID from which you can extract it.

Python documentation on [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.split) and [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall)